# Laravel 5 if statement between Carbon diffForHumans and toFormattedDatesString

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I want to write an if statement to show timestamp in diffForHumans format for timestamps less than less than 5 days old and in toFormattedDatesString for anything older than that.

For example today is 31/10/17, so timestamp for 28/10/2017 should show - 3 days ago and timestamp for 20/10/2017 should show Oct 20, 2017.

What logic should I use to achieve this?

Comment: What did you try so far ? and add some code !!

Comment: Go through the [Carbon API Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Then show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Model `e.g A.php`, create an accessor like this,

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute(){
    if($this->created_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) > 5){
       return $this->created_at->toFormattedDateString();
    }else{
       return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
    }
}
```

and in your view you can access it as

```
{!! $a->created_at !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Carbon you can do that like this.

## 1

Code

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '28/10/2017')->diffForHumans();
```

Result

```
3 days
```

## 2

Code

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '28/10/2017')->toFormattedDateString();
```

Result

```
Oct 28, 2017
```